# From Avid Media Composer to DVD?

Tags: file-formats, avid, video-quality

I have a 1920x1080i project (a 50 minute film) in Avid Media Composer (version 3).

How can I make a high-quality DVD from my project?

Specifically:

- Can I export straight from Avid to a DVD format or should I use some intermediary software (Sorenson squezee etc.) to convert the output from Avid?
- Do you have any specific workflow that gives good results? I.e. Avid (fill in export settings) => DVDit or Avid (fill in export settings) => DVD Studio Pro or other ...